# How to get computed style of a HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, dom

no jQuery. pure javascript.

e.g. Use element.height but I got nothing.

I ever seen code like below befow:

```
(ele.style || ele)[styleName]
```

but I forgot what it use to.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at:

- [Get the rendered style of an element](http://robertnyman.com/2006/04/24/get-the-rendered-style-of-an-element/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

There are some pointers in http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html

also, google `clientHeight offsetHeight`  and you will find info on height.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.