# Javascript style.left is empty string

Tags: javascript

```
next.onclick = function() { 
    move('left', li_items[0]);
};

var move = function(direction, el) {
    pos = el.style[direction].split('px')[0];
    pos = parseInt(pos, 10) + 10; 
    el.style[direction] = pos + 'px';
};
```

I'm using the simple code above to try and move an element. Now when I breakpoint on this, the value of `el.style[direction]` is: `" "`. So then when i try to do anything with it, it breaks. Why would this be? Isn't `style.left` supposed to return an integer?

Comment: If you want to get such values easily, use jQuery. It has various methods to get the position of an element - as a number in pixels, no matter what units the CSS uses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why would this be?

Presumably because it hasn't been set to anything.

> Isn't style.left supposed to return an integer?

No. It is supposed to return a string containing the value of the CSS left property as set directly on the element (either by setting the JS property itself or by using a style attribute). It does not get a value from the cascade and it should only be an integer if the value is 0 (since all other lengths require units).

See [How to get computed style of a HTMLElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953353/how-to-get-computed-style-of-a-htmlelement) if you want to get the computed value for the property rather than what I described in the previous paragraph.

Comment: The answer you linked to provides me with another link to click. Wonderful. Could you possibly include the relevant bits of code in your answer?

Comment: @ElliotBonneville—here is the relevant [W3C reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSview-getComputedStyle) and the relevant [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle). That took about 30 seconds in a reasonable search engine.

Comment: @RobG: Cool, thanks. Better than a rabbit trail of links. :-)

Comment: +1 for "all other lengths require UNITS". I was getting tricked by that.

Answer (score 0):

`style` provides the original style as calculated from the CSS, not the updated and possibly dynamic style. You probably want `currentStyle` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment.

In your code:

```
> pos = el.style[direction].split('px')[0];
> pos = parseInt(pos, 10) + 10;
```

The split in the first line is superfluous, in the second line `parseInt` will convert (say) `10px` to the number `10` just as effectively (and more efficiently) than what you have.

```
pos = parseInt(el.style[direction], 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
next.onclick = function() { 
    move('left', li_items[0]);
};

var move = function(direction, el) {
    var lft = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el)[direction];
    pos = parseFloat(lft);
    pos = parseInt(pos, 10) + 10; 
    el.style[direction] = pos + 'px';
};
```

***Note:** like Elliot said you'll have to get the currentStyle/computedStyle.  Here's [a way](http://blog.stchur.com/2006/06/21/css-computed-style/) to make it cross-browser, however when applying styles via JS, this is one good case where some sort of framework (eg Prototype [Scriptaculous], jQuery) would be useful.*

Answer (score 0):

This could be helpful.Add an onclick in the button.

```
function move() {
        var 1 = document.getElementById("2");
        var count = 1;
        var id = setInterval(frame, 100);
        function frame() {
            width++;
            1.style.left = width + '%';
        }
    }function stop(){
            clearInterval(id);
     }
```